# Estimate Disk space for MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql db which has data up to few GBs. Additionally, I execute LIMIT queries which require some free space to be available for execution. I'm using C#.Net to know the total and available disk space. Is there a way to know how much free space is needed to execute SORT/LIMIT queries successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no 100% accurate way to estimate this value.
It very depends of MySQL configuration parameters and server RAM available.

Comment: yep. But I'm not finding a pointer towards the solution. When MySQL executes LIMIT/SORT queries it must be storing some temporary data on disk. So the minimum amount of memory on DISK (not RAM) needed to execute a successful query that we need to per-calculate.